# ForwardRef type based on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ref

I am using React + Typescript. I am working on a component that can return dynamic HTML element depends on props:

```
interface Props {
  label?: string;
}

const DynamicComponent = forwardRef<
  HTMLButtonElement | HTMLLabelElement,
  Props
>((props, ref) => {
  if (props.label) {
    return (
      <label ref={ref as React.ForwardedRef<HTMLLabelElement>}>
        {props.label}
      </label>
    );
  }
  return (
    <button ref={ref as React.ForwardedRef<HTMLButtonElement>}>BUTTON</button>
  );
});
```

Is it possible to type `ref`'s interface in a way that will depend on the `label` prop?

```
export default function App() {
  const btnRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null); // Allowed
  const labelRef = useRef<HTMLLabelElement>(null); // Allowed
 //  const labelRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null); // Not allowed, because `label` prop was not provided
  return (
    <>
      <DynamicComponent ref={btnRef} />
      <DynamicComponent ref={labelRef} label="my label" />
    </>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-surf-gx80x?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that we need to use function overloading, with higher order function pattern and typeguards:

**FIXED**

```js
import React, { forwardRef, useRef, Ref } from 'react'

interface Props {
  label?: string;
}

// typeguard
const isLabelRef = (props: Props, ref: React.ForwardedRef<any>): ref is React.ForwardedRef<HTMLLabelElement> => {
  return true // ! NON IMPLEMENTED
}

// typeguard
const isButtonRef = (props: Props, ref: React.ForwardedRef<any>): ref is React.ForwardedRef<HTMLButtonElement> => {
  return true // ! NON IMPLEMENTED
}

// Higher order COmponent with overloads
function DynamicComponent<T extends HTMLButtonElement>(reference: Ref<T>): any
function DynamicComponent<T extends HTMLLabelElement>(reference: Ref<T>, props: Props): any
function DynamicComponent<T extends HTMLElement>(reference: Ref<T> | undefined, props?: Props) {

  const WithRef = forwardRef<HTMLElement, Props>((_, ref) => {
    if (props && isLabelRef(props, ref)) {
      return (
        <label ref={ref}>
          {props.label}
        </label>
      );
    }

    if (props && isButtonRef(props, ref)) {
      return (
        <button ref={ref}>BUTTON</button>
      );
    }
    return null
  });

  return <WithRef ref={reference} />
}


export default function App() {
  const btnRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null); // Allowed
  const labelRef = useRef<HTMLLabelElement>(null); // Allowed

  return (
    <>
      {DynamicComponent(btnRef)}
      {DynamicComponent(labelRef, { label: 'sdf' })}
    </>
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBm0A7ilACbL7YCuAzkpXAL4FQQhwDkUqGnAUP2AA7GEij50SOAAU2YWrn5w4AGxQAjJKoD8ALji0YUEQHMA3Pyb80EYUbjBaAGU3bGAXjgAKMPNoGchAK2Dz4BsjoMAB0AGLEpGRIFEj4ADwowgCeAHwAlAZhjoqRGHEJ5MmUaQASACoAss6uWqoAoqpIIEiiOXAefTjKcDww1FDCcMbU0gD0s3AAhHAAcgDyK3AAkg0yzm0NbSt1bQAiVoK29vBOAELUMDB2nj5%20wQGy-qGpEbwx8VASJUUulMrkCiNUsVEH9yoDElVUrVGs57o87B0uj0YH0BkoVKNxpNpnMFst1psdnsDkcTudrPx8NRhBhgHY4KcssIUCBgGgAMLsSDCbFpOqYHK%20fwGHAsABkMKi0UoAEFHiYNA8kLRkU00U9hJjur0IWDGczWezOdzeQKhXZReLJW8FDK1G5VAYjCZhKZmHAFaUYqr1cBNWIdfUmi1tEbsfkDGamSyYGzJtaeXzBeAHaIxc7pZ93gHFWUQ8Yw1qdXV8kphlcHAB1YAwAAWL0I8PI1Sj%2006xqwRYUku8AH1vvg8v1BsMVMB8D4nDHVJQpe8J3kp0MVDvIWMJj5Z7u4Gl1K1IfgPDgwkwckfj7gXbRomftNYHyo0rNX6o7w%208pYu4Mru86LrQ%20rPKka4hBem74sehIHt4947mk4YGheV43jktwAKp1HUGxfuhdh-seAFHu%20O6IZMwjUKoqjDEwFHDDRJ7Nm2jCzHeDL8EgAAekCwHASSSPR8DJpakwqmAYDeFu9Z2A4GgwMILx0AwSK9hBhr9vG3h0QxAFwPMcAqgxEBEMkinXO6rTqfQPYosuca9AZ9GqMZpnmaolnWaxSD7pMyG7mkZG7qZeEERsKFpBmtrZsK2KYTgKlqakLDcSZCwQAA1nZ2jQsIEDwDwACO1DADwZCxfFWb2iKogpWllAsD%20V6cLQZD4JwmV9KZAlgEgGDJHA4hsFAggPqZzgqrcbTOLVXKZnaOaNaVqRXj%20rUmf1CyDcNYhkGNUATdgP7QuVlXVUtNr1WtyVhFtHo7e1OCcK22i%20b1u3ZXAeXnR60JvAAbsASQ1aF3HDBRTBAA)

As you might have noticed, I use only `props` from `DynamicComponent`.

Also `T` generic parameter serves for narrowing the `ref` type

I left `isButtonRef` and `isLabelRef` unimplemented

**UPDATE**
Seems that my previous example is useless. Sorry for that.

My bad. I have already fixed it.

As an alternative solution, you can override built in `forwardRef` function.

```js
interface Props {
  label: string;
}

declare module "react" {
  function forwardRef<T extends HTMLButtonElement, P>(
    render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLButtonElement, never>
  ): ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    PropsWithRef<{ some: number }> & RefAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
  >;

  function forwardRef<T extends HTMLLabelElement, P extends { label: string }>(
    render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLLabelElement, { label: string }>
  ): ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    PropsWithRef<{ label: string }> & RefAttributes<HTMLLabelElement>
  >;
}

const WithLabelRef = forwardRef<HTMLLabelElement, Props>((props, ref) => (
  <label ref={ref}>{props.label}</label>
));

const WithButtonRef = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement>((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref}>{props}</button>
));

function App() {
  const btnRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
  const labelRef = useRef<HTMLLabelElement>(null);
  const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <WithButtonRef ref={btnRef} />
      <WithLabelRef ref={labelRef} label="my label" />
      <WithLabelRef ref={divRef} label="my label" /> //expected error
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It almost works, but in the sandbox with a small react app I am getting "Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?"

Comment: Frankly, I did not check compiled code in react sandbox. Could you please share the link. Probably I dod not take into account some react restrictions

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-bouman-skf65. I also tried to fix one more react issue with different ref types there, but without success now. Is it possible to do something similar without overloading? Something like `function DynamicComponent(props: EmptyProp | LabelProp | ButtonProp)`?

Comment: It does not work (at leaset did not work) because you removed `<WithRef />` from my solution. Please paste my solution without any modifications insode sandbox